# Share modal to the social network

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where on click of the button I am triggering a modal with some information and social networking buttons in the modal footer.

When click on the social networking button i want the url which is sent should show a modal directly instead of showing the page

Route:

```
.state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            templateUrl: 'views/mainView.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
   })
```

Controller:This is where i am opening a modal on button click

```
$scope.fnModal = function() {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: ISOURCE_TOGGLE.set,
                backdrop: 'static',
                templateUrl: 'views/modal/rescheduleModalView.html',
                controller: 'ModalCtrl'

            })
        }
```

Modal ctrl: This is where the modal should be share on click of social share button using Socialshare service

```
   $scope.socialShare = function() {
    Socialshare.share({
        'provider': 'facebook',
        'attrs': {
            'socialshareUrl': window.location.href
        }
    });
}
```

but here the main page is getting shared where as i want the modal should be shared directly

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive for modal.

Inject the directive in your controller and use it in html as follows.

`<modal data-some-attr="value"></modal>`

Answer (score 0):

If your modal content is static, you can just add a query parameter in your URL when you open your modal (function `$scope.fnModal`) with this :

```
$state.transitionTo('main', {modal: 'true'}, { notify: false });
```

You don't change anything in your modal controller.

When an user comes to your page `main`, you have to check if in your url you have the query parameter modal sets to true. If yes, you open the modal or else just show the page without modal.

Comment: My modal is gets the data from the main page using resolve